# Photoshop проблемы с версиями macOS

Tags: macos, photoshop, macbook

Я понимаю, что данный вопрос может вызвать диссонанс среди пользователей данного сообщества, но я прошу помощи, так как я не нашел абсолютно никакой информации по теме моего вопроса.

**Проблема**

У меня в пользовании для работы очень старый MacBook Air late 2010.
Думаю, пользователи MacBook понимают, что это за *старик*. И, понятное дело, он не потянет *Photoshop CC*. А мой основной PC накрылся буквально неделю назад.

**Вопрос**

Могу ли я как-то установить более раннюю версию Photoshop, например, Photoshop CS5?

Насколько я смог заметить, сейчас компания (как минимум для MacOS) использует систему обновлений, и возможно скачать только текущую версию, актуальную на данный момент. Если кто то знает, как можно или где можно установить или скачать старую версию Photoshop, - подскажите! Ибо верстать из psd на глаз просто нереально, - сами понимаете.

Answer (score 2):

Установить, разумеется, можете.

Варианты:  (Пиратские способы, конечно, предлагать не буду :))

1. Купить лицензионный диск с действующей лицензией. Новый у ритейлера уже наверняка не найти, но купить у бывшего владельца можете (как пример, на [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/p/Adobe-InDesign-CS5-Full-Version-for-Mac-65062470/128138559?iid=283235275317)). Отмечу, что, скорее всего, при установке придётся связываться с техподдержкой и объяснять, как вы приобрели продукт (есть опыт, проблем не возникало, однако, не совсем понятно, как быть с продуктом, изначально продававшимся в другой стране)
2. В свое время CS5 давали в виде пробной версии на 30 дней. Можно поискать в сети этот образ и установить его, как временное решение. Возможно, вам удастся и зарегистрировать его за деньги, у меня такого опыта нет. Возможно, не сработает - из-за даты, к примеру.